# Is a Blocking System Call in a State Machine a Call Event

Tags: uml, system-calls, state-machine

At the transition between states in an UML state machine you can have a trigger, a guard and an effect.

If I do a blocking system call (e.g. select() on Posix systems or a wait_for_edge() at a Raspberry Pi) is this a call event because the state machine is blocked and I can not proceed this operation?

Can I model this state machine this way or do I have to use a different mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a blocking call, the state stays where it is. You will show such calls as `<<do>>` operation inside a state.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A blocking call inside a state machine violates the universally assumed run-to-completion semantics of event processing inside state machines. This is because un-blocking (return from a blocking call) is an alternative way of delivering event to the state machine. Problem is that this "back-door" event arrives while the state machine is already in the middle of processing the original event. Also, there is no clear way of showing such "un-blocking" events in a state machine diagram. For these reasons any blocking calls (not even in-line delay()) should be avoided inside state machines, or inside any truly event-driven system for that matter. Events should be delivered strictly through the event-loop. Such event-loop can block to wait for events, but this is **outside** any state machine.